# Json: Unicode charecter '%' escapes at the end of the statement

Tags: c++, json, escaping

In my code when I try to print the '%' character over the command line it escapes(i.e it is not printed on the command prompt), i believe the Json compiler is escaping the character.

I am using Cajun - C++ source code for Json

What should I do to retain the '%' Character. Below is snippet of my code and Writter.cpp

Code Snippet:

```
progVal = mrLdProgress_.fgi.reProgress.progress;
objVd["Progress%"] = json::Number((int)((U32)(progVal)* 100 /0xFFFF));
    if(progVal == 0xFFFF)
    {
        objVd["Status"] =json::String("Completed");
        objVd["Estimated Time Left"] = json::String("-");
    }
    else
    {
        objVd["Status"] =json::String("In progress");
    }
```

Code snippet of Writter.cpp where actually it prints Json "name":"value" :

```
if(it->name != "My Message" && it->name != "Begin Table" && it->name != "End Table")
        {
            if(needNewLine){ Writer::putchar(','); Writer::putchar('\n'); needNewLine=false;}

            int tabs=m_nTabDepth; while(tabs) { Writer::putchar('\t'); --tabs; } Writer::putchar('"');

            if(it->name.c_str()[it->name.length()-1]=='&') it->name = it->name.substr(0,it->name.length()-1);            
            Writer::printf("%s%s",it->name.c_str(),"\" : ");

            Write_i(it->element);
            needNewLine=true;
        }

int Writer::printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    char buff[4096];
    char *ptr=buff;

    if(!format) return 0;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
#ifndef OS_PREBOOT
    int ret = vsprintf(buff,format,args);
#else
    int ret = print(&ptr,format,args);
#endif
    va_end(args);

    cache_string(buff);

    return ret;
}
```

The string"Progress%" is actual culprit here, only the Progress is printed escaping the % character.

I have tried adding the control character "\" to the below line

```
> Writer::printf("%s%s",it->name.c_str(),"\" : ");
```

so that the % symbol gets printed on the command prompt but i get a compiler error.

So please help me regarding this issue.

And when I add '%\' in the above statement it works, the symbol % is printed on the command prompt.

Output of the issue :

```
{
"My Operation":[
{
        "Operation Status" : {
                "Count of operation" : 0,
                "Status" : "Success",
                "Description" : "None"
        },
        "Response Data" : {
                "Count Operation Status" : [
                        {
                                "Count" : 0,
                                "Operation" : "INIT",
                                "Progress" : "-",
                                "Status" : "Not in progress",
                        }
                ]
        }
}
]
}
```

As you can see in the output Progress% is not displaying only Progress is displaying.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: I am not using Json library, I am using the Cajun - C++ source code for Json

Comment: That would have been useful information to include in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have added that..